# Adding an Image to DOM Dynamically Using Range.insertNode()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I dynamically insert an IMG element into the DOM using Range.insertNode() ?

My HTML:

```
<div class="css_class_for_div" style="height: 250px;" contenteditable="true">
    <img src="/path/to/my/image/myimage.png" alt="/myimage.png" title="/myimage.png" class="css_class_for_image" e_resid="/myimage.png" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span class="css_class_for_span"></span>
</div>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="insert image" />
```

MY JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var src = "/path/to/my/other/image/image2.png";
    var title = "/image2.png";
    var cssClassname = "css_class_for_image";
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("css_class_for_div");
    var el = list[0];
    var selRanges = el.getSelection();
    if (selRanges.rangeCount > 0) {
        var curRange = selRanges.getRangeAt(0); // Range object
        if (curRange.toString().length == 0) {
            var imageNode = document.createElement('img');
            imageNode.src = src;
            imageNode.alt = title;
            imageNode.title = title;
            imageNode.className = cssClassname;
            curRange.insertNode(imageNode);
        }
    }
},false);
```

[[Link to fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/coner/8bdmp6d9)

The above code doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some hints: 1. Look at your JS console, it will help you quickly trace and solve almost/all such errors. 2. Isn't `getSelection()` a method of the document node? 3. Does `el` have a `contentWindow` property? - http://jsfiddle.net/8bdmp6d9/10/

Comment: Using window.getSelection() did the trick.  Thanks @techfoobar !

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to insert Image2 into the first occurrence of a div with classname = css_class_for_div using [Range.InsertNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/insertNode), you can use the following code.

I had to use

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(your div);
range.insertNode(your image);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/8bdmp6d9/13/)

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    debugger;
    var range = document.createRange();
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("css_class_for_div");
    if (list.length > 0) {
        var el = list[0];
        range.selectNode(el);
        var imageNode = getImageNode();
        range.insertNode(imageNode);
    }
}, false);

function getImageNode() {
    var src = "/path/to/my/other/image/image2.png";
    var title = "/image2.png";
    var cssClassname = "css_class_for_image";
    var imageNode = document.createElement('img');
    imageNode.src = src;
    imageNode.alt = title;
    imageNode.title = title;
    imageNode.className = cssClassname;
    return imageNode;
}
```

Comment: I need to insert at the point of the current selection, not always at the beginning. Thanks.